# After setting up Dagger-Hilt, several packages are created

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

[packages image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eempd.png) After setting up Dagger-Hilt, several packages are created, including:

dagger.hilt.internal.aggregatedroot.codegen:

hilt_aggregated_deps:

To avoid these packages, what should I do? Thanks in Advance!